# Showing tooltip with touch-and-hold on touch devices

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

The behavior of a mouse over is that a tooltip is shown on dc.js charts (.title attribute).

How can I make a touch device show this same tooltip when a "touch and hold" (see option 1 at: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98628/how-can-i-display-tool-tips-on-a-touchscreen-or-is-there-a-better-way) is performed by the user?

So every default dc.js mouse over behavior should be converted to default "touch and hold" behavior on touch devices, using the dc.js charts on a webpage.

Comment: There is no such thing as hovering on a touchscreen, it's all touches. Here's a [fairly comprehensive Q&A on possible alternatives](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98628/how-can-i-display-tool-tips-on-a-touchscreen-or-is-there-a-better-way). Once you decide on a strategy, please edit your question with more specifics. You might also search for D3-specific "touch tooltip" solutions, since this isn't really a dc.js specific question. If you find a solution, please answer your own question or at add a comment linking to what you settled on.

Comment: I updated the question based on your suggestions.

Comment: I did a bit of searching but it didn't look like there was an all-in-one solution. I'm adding [d3] to the tags since this isn't really a [dc.js] specific question.